# mkdir com problema na permissão da pasta criada

Tags: php, linux

Quando crio a pasta, ele cria, mas não cria com a permissão correta, impedindo de criar a próxima pasta, o `chmod` na pasta criada vem 411.

```
mkdir("../../UPLOADS/$albumName","0775", true);
mkdir("../../UPLOADS/$albumName/thumbs","0775", true);
```

Comment: Já tentou passar o modo como inteiro e não como *string*? Veja na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mkdir.php). Aliás, leia sobre o terceiro parâmetro. Se você usar como `true` não precisa chamar a função duas vezes.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você utiliza a função `mkdir` com o parâmetro `$mode`, você deve passar esse parâmetro como `int`.

Quando você passa como `string`, o *PHP* tenta, automaticamente, converter para `int`. Durante essa conversão, o valor é modificado, passando de `0775` para `755`.

Isso ocorre pois o PHP, por padrão, não trabalha com Octal, diferente do comando `chmod` do Unix.

Como o Linux trabalha com esse valor em octal, você acaba errando com essa conversão. Exemplo:

**Valor em Octal**

```
0777 (octal) == binário 0b 111 111 111    == permissões rwxrwxrwx   (== decimal 511)
```

**Valor e decimal**

```
777 (decimal) == binário 0b 1 100 001 001 == permissões sr----x--x  (== octal 1411)
```

Por isso, o recomendado *(O correto na verdade)* é passar como inteiro.

```
mkdir("/path/to/folder", 0775, true);
```

Comment: Ele cria com a permissão 01341  somente 775

Comment: @FernandoSantana, você tem que colocar o 0 na frente. O correto é 0775